# How to populate a obj recived from middleware in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 2 middlewares mounted on an express router the first middleware gives me an obj which I can access on `req` in the next middleware where I need to populate the received Obj and return the details as a res.

**Here is how i am trying to run the populate query**

```
const storeObjWithDetails = await storeObj.populate('StoreId').populate('Products.PrdId').execPopulate();
```

**This is how my `storeObj` looks like in JSON**

```
    "storeObj": [
        {
            "_id": "6184ddd522fb0a25f0419ed0",
            "StoreId": "6162a2008d0dd0235021b2bc",
            "StoreName": "Store Name",
            "StoreImage": "Link to Image Removed",
            "Products": [
                {
                    "_id": "6184ddeb22fb0a25f0419ef5",
                    "PrdId": "616d5d7165e5a7191cfbd87b",
                    "PrdName": "PrdName",
                    "PrdImage": "Link to Image Removed",
                    "Qty": 10
                },
                {
                    "_id": "6184e08baf2d9e1880cf3083",
                    "PrdId": "616d5d5065e5a7191cfbd877",
                    "PrdName": "PrdName",
                    "PrdImage": "Link to Image Removed",
                    "Qty": 5
                },
                {
                    "_id": "6184e092af2d9e1880cf308f",
                    "PrdId": "616d5d5a65e5a7191cfbd879",
                    "PrdName": "PrdName",
                    "PrdImage": "Link to Image Removed",
                    "Qty": 5
                }
            ]
        }
```

`storeObj` will always have one Store and will contain an array of Products in this case, I have tried to make the query as common as possible since I cannot disclose the actual use case.

The error I receive is as follows
`"message": "storeObj.populate is not a function",`

**Model Defination**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    prop1: { type: string },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    storeObjParent: {
      storeObj: [
        {
          StoreId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Store',
          },
          StoreName: { type: String },
          StoreImage: { type: String },
          Products: [
            {
              PrdId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Product',
              },
              PrdName: { type: String },
              PrdImage: { type: String },
              Qty: { type: Number },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

const extractedSchema = mongoose.model('ExtractedSchema', Schema);
```

Comment: instead of populate you could use `$lookup`

Comment: Sorry @mohammadNaimi i have zero clue how lookup works could you please re-factor the above code using $lookup

Comment: @NishantSVispute Can you post your `storeObj` model definition?